# Saving object with linkedlist - error on API 10

Tags: android, exception, linked-list

when saving an object with LinkedList on android API 10 I obtain an error:

> ```
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845): FATAL EXCEPTION:
> Thread-17 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no char field 'exponential' 08-10
> 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):    at
> java.io.EmulatedFields.put(EmulatedFields.java:459) 08-10
> 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):    at
> java.io.EmulatedFieldsForDumping.put(EmulatedFieldsForDumping.java:83)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.writeObject(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:591)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-10
> 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-10 14:37:45.091:
> E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1062)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1008)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.text.DecimalFormat.writeObject(DecimalFormat.java:1215) 08-10
> 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-10
> 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-10 14:37:45.091:
> E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1205)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:973) 08-10
> 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-10
> 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-10 14:37:45.091:
> E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:973) 08-10
> 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-10
> 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):    at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-10 14:37:45.091:
> E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at
> java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
> 08-10 14:37:45.091: E/AndroidRuntime(29845):  at java.io.Ob
> ```

I don't where is glitch and I don't think that linkedlist is a problem as it is since API 1, but never the less it doesn't occur on android API 18, any idea where's a problem?

Saving:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput("shelf.obj", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        out.writeObject(listOfShelfs);
        out.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //catch
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //catch
    }
```

object to save:

```
private static HashMap<String, MessageShelf> listOfShelfs = new HashMap<String, MessageShelf>();
```

MessageShelf:

```
public class MessageShelf implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Friend correspodent;
Calendar lastSeen;
Calendar lastSend;
boolean secure;
Queue<MessageList> historyMessagesLists=new LinkedList<MessageList>();
public String lastMessageBody = "";
public Calendar lastDate;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be [Bug 14495: Android 2.3 and 3.0's DecimalFormatSymbols serialization is broken.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14495)

Comment: But by which attribute of that object is DecimalFormatSymbol used? Calendar?

Comment: @Primosz: you could remove the attributes of MessageShelf one by one to figure out which one causes the DecimalFormatSymbol.